# Aliasing `grep -w 'label for'` only searches for the first word (label)

Tags: linux, shell, grep, alias

```
alias cgrep='current_dir_grep'
function current_dir_grep_exact {
grep -w $1 .
}
alias cgrepe='current_dir_grep_exact'
```

`grep -w 'label for' .` works but doing `cgrepe 'label for'` only searches for the occurrences of `label` while I would like to find the occurences `label for` in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the argument in quotes:

```
grep -w "$1" .
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! May I add that using single quotes instead doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash(1)`, aliases *do not take arguments*. It sometimes looks like they do, but they don't. Use a function.

Comment: But how do I write these functions so I can use them everywhere like an alias?